# Ui namespace in Qt widget projects

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

I have a Qt widget project called "SeasonCreator" and am wondering about the structure of a Qt widget project.

The ui_seasoncreator.h file is hidden, but when you look into it, it defines a namespace called "Ui" and in it is a declaration of a class SeasonCreator, which inherits from Ui_SeasonCreator, which is the c.

In the seasoncreator.h file, there is also a namespace called "Ui" also with a declaration of a class called "SeasonCreator". When I click to find its original declaration it leads me to the declaration of Ui::SeasonCreator in the ui_seasoncreator.h file.

**What is the purpose for these namespace and classes? Do the two definitions relate?**

**Do any of these Ui::SeasonCreator declarations have anything to do with the custom SeasonCreator class in seasoncreator.h?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the purpose for these namespace and classes?

The code in ui_XXX.h is code that is automatically generated for you when you use designer to create a form.  It's put into the Ui namespace.

> Do the two definitions relate?

I'm assuming you're referring to something that looks like this:

```
namespace Ui { class SeasonCreator; }
```

which is a forward declaration of the class that is part of the generated code that gives your class access to the widgets in your custom form.

> Do any of these Ui::SeasonCreator declarations have anything to do with the custom SeasonCreator class in seasoncreator.h?

It's what links your custom code together with the generated code. You should probably have a member variable of your custom class called `Ui::SeasonCreator *ui`, which is the object you use to access the generated Ui classes.

Comment: I see, the SeasonCreator class in ui_seasoncreator.h inherits all members of the class that creates all the widgets (Ui_SeasonCreator). As for the second question, I was wondering if the Ui::SeasonCreator classes were the same in files ui_XXX.h and XXX.h. I believe they are, but wouldn't that be a redeclaration? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Ui::SeasonCreator and SeasonCreator are two separate classes (one's in the Ui namespace, one is not). The SeasonCreator class generally will contain an instance of Ui::SeasonCreator which is just a wrapper around the data in your form.

Comment: The Ui::SeasonCreator in seasoncreator.h does not foward declare the SeasonCreator class in seasoncreator.h? So what is it foward declaring, because there are two copies of Ui::SeasonCreator. One in seasoncreator.h, the other in ui_seasoncreator.h

Comment: ui_seasoncreator.h contains a *definition* of Ui::SeasonCreator, and your SeasonCreator.h file contains a *declaration* of an instance of that class. The SeasonCreator.h likely contains a forward declaration of Ui::SeasonCreator to help avoid unnecessary recompilations when your .ui file changes.

Comment: But Qt is declaring the Ui namespace twice? Doesn't that cause problems?

Comment: So this is just a summary. Lets say I have a namespace named X and a forward declaration of a class named Y. X::Y can be declared anywhere for however many times you want. If Y was an integer instead, X::Y can only be declared once in a file, unless extern is provided in a declaration.

Comment: More or less. It's just a forward declaration, you can forward declare a class as many times as you like. There's no need for a forward declaration of primitive types.