# In Qt MainWindow, why does an instance have a pointer to an instance?

Tags: c++, qt

The `MainWindow` code generated by QtCreator says:

```
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;    // forward-declare Ui::MainWindow (?)
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow    // Declare MainWindow class (Ui::MainWindow?)
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit                 MainWindow( QWidget *parent = 0 );
    /**/                    ~MainWindow( void );
    // ...
private:
    Ui::MainWindow          *ui;
    // ...
};
```

`main()` does:

```
    MainWindow w;
    w.show( );
```

`MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent )` does:

```
    ui( new Ui::MainWindow )    // Initialization
```

I don't understand why a `MainWindow` instance has a pointer to another/a different/a new `MainWindow` in its `ui` instance variable.  I instrumented the `MainWindow::MainWindow` constructor, and I can see it's only being called once.  So presumably that's the automatic variable on the stack in `main()`.  But what about the `ui( new Ui::MainWindow )` that happens in the constructor?  That's creating a `MainWindow` on the heap, isn't it?  How is it being initialized?

Maybe the subsequent `ui->setupUi( this )` in the constructor is doing some magic?  Otherwise, it seems like this would recurse to stack crash, as each `new MainWindow` creates a new `MainWindow` to populate its `ui` instance variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ui namespace in Qt widget projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943433/ui-namespace-in-qt-widget-projects)

Comment: `Ui::MainWindow` is not `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two *different* classes in play here:

```
::MainWindow
::Ui::MainWindow
```

I wouldn't go so far as to say they are not related - but they are not the same class.

Comment: Ah, OK, I thought the forward declaration just allowed you to use `MainWindow` as an alias for `Ui::MainWindow`.  I guess there's a declaration of `Ui::MainWindow` somewhere else that's managed automagically by the Qt build process.

Thanks!

Comment: No.  If there was a `using ui::MainWindow`, then they would be same class.

Answer (score 3):

The `Ui::MainWindow` class is code generated by `uic` from the respective QtDesigner file.
It is not a widget but a helper that contains code to populate a widget.

So in your case it is code that is used to populate a `QMainWindow` derived class named `MainWindow`.

`Ui::MainWindow` is held as a pointer to allow forward declaration and avoid build dependencies of code including `MainWindow`'s header to the generate code (which will change everytime you change something in QtDesigner)